# Can Photoshop apply duotone through adjustment layers?

Tags: photoshop

Is it possible to apply duotone through an adjustment layer?

Like this:

```
Adjustment layer: duotone
Adjustment layer: black and white
Ground layer: original color file (smart object)
```

I don't need this for printing, just saving the final result as a JPEG for screen display. I want the duotone to be adjustable in the same way as "Mode > greyscale > duotone" (choosing colors, setting curves).

Comment: Do you mean duotone? I think 'duotone' means 'duplex' in German...

Comment: @BobT - from what I can gather, Duplex appears to be what Duotone is referred to as in some other languages.  I'm not sure what language it was, but all the results I found were in a foreign language and looked like Duotone images.

Comment: If duotone, do you need a real duotone (an image prepared for duotone printing on an offset lithography press) or just an image that *looks* like a duotone (for screen display or inkjet/chromogenic/CMYK process printing)? The latter can be done with a gradient map in Color blend mode.

Comment: Than you for your help. Yes, duotone. "Duplex" is not a German word, so I assumed it was the international technical term and did not consult a dictionary. I edited my question to (hopefully) answer your return questions. @StanRogers Thank you for that answer. That is a way to do it, but it lacks a preview etc. and will be very hard to fine-tune. But it certainly is a possibility, if there is no other.

Comment: English is a silly language. Here in the US at least, outside of scientific use _duplex_ almost exclusively means either a) a two-family house or b) printing on both sides of a sheet of paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the process is a bit of a pain in the butt to set up manually, fake duotone/tritone/quadtone images can be created using a "monochroming" layer¹ and a Gradient Map adjustment layer set to Color blend mode.

If you are using a Smart Object as your original image, though, you can create a conversion-and-preview template image that will speed up the process tremendously. Adobe guru Julianne Kost provides both the method and a template (using the CS6 gradient presets, but adaptable to other versions) [on her Adobe blog](http://blogs.adobe.com/jkost/2012/06/photographic-toning-presets-in-photoshop-cs6.html). There is also a [video tutorial](http://blogs.adobe.com/jkost/2012/07/video-tutorial-photographic-toning-presets-in-photoshop-cs6.html) available.

Setting up custom gradients will be a bit of a pain, but once they're done they're done, and you can use the templating technique to choose the best match for your image quickly. It won't be *quite* as handy as a good B&W conversion plugin with presets (like Nik Siver Efex Pro or Topaz Black & White Effects), but it'll take a lot of work out of future conversions.

---

<sup>¹ For the monochrome conversion layer, I'd suggest using a Curves adjustment layer rather than the more obvious Hue/Saturation; it will produce less tone shifting, especially when combined with contrast adjustment layers. Create a Curves layer, and drag the black point to the top. That will make the whole image white. Then set the layer blend mode to Saturation.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, that's cool. I actually found a similar tutorial explaining the same technique for an older PS version: http://tv.adobe.com/watch/learn-photoshop-cs5/creative-sepia-tones/

Answer (score 0):

It's a color mode so the actual channels change, making the method you describe not possible. Duotone can only be achieved once the image mode is converted to Grayscale.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-778ea.html

Consider maybe using Hue&Saturation or selective color or some other adjustment layer to change the duotone colors.